# Get Types Which Class Extends From

Tags: typescript

I wrote the following to get the "SuperType" of a given class/interface.

```
type SuperType<T> = T extends infer U ? U : never;
```

I understand that classes can extend from multiple classes, but I was hoping to just get the first one.

However, this always returns the class itself, which makes sense because:

```
type x<T> = T extends T ? true : never; // true for any T
```

Is there a way to write my `SuperType<T>` type so that it gives either:

- the first class it extends from which isn't itself
- a union of classes which it extends from

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as @ryan-cavanaugh I don't believe this to be possible. What we can do is create some sort of structure that records the super type of the class in the current class. This assumes you have control over the base classes which my not be the case

This solution relies on 3.0 feature of [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897). I tried to get it working without this but things work out nicer with this:

```
class Foo { fooMethod(): void { } }
class Boo extends ext(Foo) { barMethod(): void { } }
class Baz extends ext(Boo) { bazMethod(): void { } }


type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends (...a: infer U) => void ? U : never;
type SuperTypes<T> = T extends { super: infer U } ? ArgumentTypes<U> : [];
function ext<T extends { new(): any; super?: (...a: any[]) => void }>(c: T): T & { super(p: T, ...a: SuperTypes<T>): void } {
    return c as any;
}

type AllBaseTypesOfBaz = SuperTypes<typeof Baz> // [typeof Boo, typeof Foo]
type BaseTypeOfBaz = SuperTypes<typeof Baz>[0] // typeof Boo
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're going to find a way to do this [1]

Conditional types operate on the types "themselves"; the information about the base classes of any given class are not at all present on the instance type of a class because that information is only used at the declaration site to copy down certain properties and enforce some assignability checks.

[1] I originally wrote "this is not possible" but I could be wrong (but I'm probably not)